# Data Structure for fast searching

Tags: performance, search, data-structures, grid-computing

If I have to develop an application for a data grid station of an institute. The purpose of application is to receive the data from data GRID station once in a week between 10 A.M to 10:30 A.M and then store it into a data structure and data is consist of digits only but the numbers could be very long for one entry then which data structure will be the best for given scenario from array, list, linked list, doubly linked list, queue, priority queue, stack, binary search tree, AVL trees, threaded binary tree, heap, sorted sequential array and skip list

I want to store sorted digits. The sorted data can be in ascending or descending order and the main concern is "fast and efficient searching".

Comment: Will the data be changing often?

Comment: Storing "digits" between 0 and 9 only, or any numbers?

Comment: If I have to develop an application for a data grid station of an institute. The purpose of application is to receive the data from data GRID station once in a week between 10 A.M to 10:30 A.M and then store it into a data structure and data is consist of digits only but the numbers could be very long for one entry then which data structure will be the best for given scenario.

Answer (score 1):

From your description I gather that you don't store any other data with the digits or numbers. So basically you want to know if a number is in the set or not.

Fastest way to know this, is to have an array of flags for each number. Let's say you deal with numbers from 1 to 1000. You want to know if number 200 is in the set. Look at position 200 wether the flag is true or false. You see, this is the fastest method, because you only look up one place.

As we are talking about boolean flags here, a bit is sufficient for storage. You would decide wether to store the booleans in bits, bytes, words or whatever, depending on the number of numbers, the available memory and the machine's architecture.

Having said this, you may have to deal with so many numbers that above approach is no more feasible. It would be fastest in theory, but with limited memory, swaps to hard disk, many, many reads from it, other algorithms may prove better. You would have the choice between:

- storing the numbers contiguously and perform a binary search on them
- storing the numbers in a binary tree
- using a hash algorithm

Which of these proves most efficient, again depends on your data and the machine.

Comment: If I have to develop an application for a data grid station of an institute. The purpose of application is to receive the data from data GRID station once in a week between 10 A.M to 10:30 A.M and then store it into a data structure and data is consist of digits only but the numbers could be very long for one entry then which data structure will be the best for given scenario.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot answer this. Actually I am not even sure I understand the task completely. You get, say, 10000 numbers. You store them. Then for one week, again and again you ask "has number 123456 been sent?", "has number 987654321 been sent?" and so on. Then new data is being sent. You delete the old 10000 numbers and replace them with new ones. And so on. Yes? How many numbers will be sent approximatly? What range of numbers, i.e. what are the lowest and the highest number possible? Have you understood my answer? I am asking because you give no hints as to the very basic questions related.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what type of searching you want to do. If you just want to know if a number is within your dataset, then a hash will be extremely fast and independent of the size of your dataset. And there is no need to sort, or even any concept of order.

If I may quote Larry Wall, author of Perl:

> Doing linear scans over an associative array is like trying to club
>   someone to death with a loaded Uzi.

(An associative array is synonymous with a hash.)

Comment: If I have to develop an application for a data grid station of an institute. The purpose of application is to receive the data from data GRID station once in a week between 10 A.M to 10:30 A.M and then store it into a data structure and data is consist of digits only but the numbers could be very long for one entry then which data structure will be the best for given scenario.

Comment: You receive one sequence of numbers per week? That is not a lot - a flat file would be ideal. No seriously... what type of processing do you need to do that causes it to need to be fast?

Comment: thanks for your answer. If I must have to use choose one data structure from array, list, linked list, doubly linked list, queue, priority queue, stack, binary search tree, AVL trees, threaded binary tree and heap then what would be the better choice from them

Comment: sorted sequential array and skip list